# Rename a printer for LP and LPSTAT

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, osx-lion, printer

I have a printer named "Home" set up in Mac OS X Lion:

[image: Printer Preferences]

However, when I use `lpstat -a` on the command line (to get the printer name to use with the `lp` command) I still get a non-user-friendly name:

[image: lpstat -a]

How can I change the name that `lp` and `lpstat -a` use for easier access to the printer from the terminal? I realize I can set the `LPDEST` or `PRINTER` environment variables but I'd also like to know how to rename the printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating and editing either:
`$HOME/.printers`
or system-wide
`/etc/printers.conf`
and add a line like this:

```
list|aliases|here|like|lp    THE_LONG_PRINTER_NAME_FROM_YOUR_EXAMPLE
```

@see [man page for printers](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?printers%204) for more info (like using `_default` alias for default printer)

And using alias is safer than renaming your printer because that might screw up macs printing...

It's also likely that macs use CUPS for printing and then the above example won't work. One workaround is to create a printer class with single printer on it. @see [Cups adding a printer class](http://www.cups.org/doc-1.1/sam.html#4_3_1)

Comment: I don't quite understand the format. In my home directory I made a `.printers` file with the contents `robble Officejet_6500_E710n_z__59BEAA_` but `echo "hello" | lp -d "robble"` just says `lp: The printer or class does not exist.`

Comment: Updated the answer to include some info about cups. Creating a printer class for a printer might be workable hack.

Comment: I was able to add a new name for the printer by using `lpadmin -p "Officejet_6500_E710n_z__59BEAA_" -c "robble"` followed by `lpadmin -p "robble" -E`. Thanks!